# Meteor live-ui input type=number

Tags: meteor

Im having a bit of trouble with a field. Im using meteor and am using a `input type='number'` field with `value="{{value}}"` where value is from a collection.

The problem is with `input type=number` I wont get a live update to the new value (I set in a different window) but it **does** work with `input type=text`. How would I fix this? Does anyone have the same issue?

It does show the new value when I refresh the page, though.

I've tried this with different examples and it does and doesn't work sometimes but I'm not too sure how to diagnose it.. there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Does the input have an id? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: I think it was a bug with the old version, its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Copying @Akshat's comment into an answer so it can be accepted:

> I think it was a bug with the old version, its fixed now.